# How to use dominated convergence on $\lim_{t \to \infty}\int_{(0, \infty)} \frac{1-e^{-tx}(x \ sin t + \cos t)}{1+x^2}d \lambda_1(x) $?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I find it hard to find an appropriate dominating function for the integral

> $$I:=\lim_{t \to \infty}\int_{(0, \infty)} \frac{1-e^{-tx}(x \ sin t + \cos t)}{1+x^2}d \lambda_1(x), \ t > 0 $$

Indeed if I set for $t>0$ $$f_t(x) = \frac{1-e^{-tx}(x \sin t + \cos t)}{1+x^2} $$ then $f_t \to 1/(1+x^2) $ point wise as $t \to \infty$ and changing the limit with the integral it would follow that $I= \pi /2 $

However to apply dominated convergence I need to dominate $|f_t|$ by an integrable function $g$ and I find it  hard to come up with such a function. It is easy to establish that $$|f_t(y)| \leq \frac{2+x}{1+x^2} $$
but said upper bound is not integrable on $(0, \infty)$.

I can also control the values of $x$ by splitting the integral into $(0,1)$ and $(1, \infty)$ but I don't see how I can do such with my $t>0$, I suppose that my dominating function $g$ has to be independent of $t$ and I cannot use arguments such as:

- For large enough $t>0$ consider that $xe^{-tx} \leq 1$

I also thought about using the idea of an integrable function $g$ that dominates $f_t$ almost everywhere, but couldn't come up with such a function either, in particular showing that the set where it wouldn't dominate $f_t$ is a null set.

Comment: It would be simpler to just show that $\frac{e^{-tx}(x\sin t+\cos t)}{1+x^2}$ is less than $\frac{e^{-tx}(x+1)}{1+x^2}$, whose integral goes to zero by the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: @Milind I suppose you mean the version for monotone decreasing functions, then I would also have to show that for a certain index the integral is finite on $(0, \infty)$ which might not be simpler.

Comment: Here you can show that for $t=1$ the function is integrable; $xe^{-x}$ is eventually decreasing, so beyond that point, say $x_0$, $\frac{e^{-x}(x+1)}{x^2+1} < \frac{c}{x^2+1}$ which is integrable, and it's clear the function is integrable from $(0, x_0)$.

Comment: Essentially this function $\frac{e^{-x}(x+1)}{x^2+1}$ will do as the dominating function you asked for as well, since the behavior of the functions for $t<1$ won't affect the limit.

Comment: @Milind that was part of my confusion, I see that the given function would dominate $f_t$, but I don't find it clear that such a function is legit reading through the statement of the theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem. The only thing mentioned there is that $|f_t| \leq g$ so I am  uncertain if I can just split $t$ into two cases. Of course it wont affect the point wise limit convergence, but it doesn't dominate $f_t$ for all $t>0$, so to be rigorous I'd also have to show that the set where said function does not dominate $f_t$ is a null set right?

Comment: The wording in the article says that the domination should hold for all $n$ in the index set; here you are modifying the index set to only include $t\geq 1$ and using that the limit is the same as with the previous index set. This is fine. The MCT approach avoids these annoyances.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience and assistance, I appreciate it.